# Closing a Question causes "Hot Network Questions" to refresh

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I sometimes see a question that needs closing, and in the course of closing the question, my eyes will glance over to the right to see if there are any interesting network questions.  Invariably, I'll see one right after I hit the "Close" button and the page will refresh, causing the hot network questions to refresh.

Since refreshing the page causes the Hot Network questions to reload, can we change that? It's getting to be annoying to lose questions I might be interested in because of a page reload. (this is in the span of a minute from initial page load to close to reload)

Comment: this is only a problem if you're a diamond, when your the 5th vote, or gold badge hammering

Comment: @Roombatron5000 Seems like the diamond also has some disadvantages :)

Comment: there is a workaround, go to [full list](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) and find it over there

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with closing,  just refresh the page to see it change.  By design, no doubt.

Comment: @HansPassant The reason I involve closing is that I'd expect refreshing the page to change the Hot Networks questions (although I hope it's a bit stickier than its current state, which seems to be 15-20 seconds of cache, or I just caught it lucky), but I wouldn't expect taking an action on the same page (where I don't explicitly refresh the page) to affect what shows up in the Hot Networks list.